# What kind of WPF control to use?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I want to create a 2D control that looks like a can. One color on the bottom and another color on the side. I will place many instances of this control on a canvas, and the canvas inside av viewbox.

[image]

I need support for tooltip, rightclick and drag&drop. It also has to support databinding and resizing.

What is the best way to create this control? Any advise is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My advice is make a `VisualBrush` which has the drawing of the can as its contents. Then each item would be a `Rectangle` (which will support the features you need), and the Rectangle's Fill property will be set to the `VisualBrush`

Comment: Thanks! Can I bind a property to the color of the can in that case? Is clickingevent only catched inside the can or inside the whole rectangle?

Comment: as long as the VisualBrush is inside a style for the Rectangle. The Click event would be for the whole Rectangle unless you did something a lot more complex